# Actualizar desde ajax a nodejs

Tags: ajax, nodejs

Estoy con este esquema de ajax que me genera mis registros y dentro de ellos tambien me genera un boton de clase "return-boton" para actualizar un campo en mi base de datos:

```
$('#getRegistros').on('click', function(){
$.ajax({
  url: '/add',
  success: function(registros){
    let tbody = $('tbody');
    tbody.html('');
    registros.forEach(registro =>{
      tbody.append(`
        <tr>
          <td id="cod_history">${registro.cod_history}</td>
          <td class="name_person">${registro.name_person}</td>
          <td class="specialty">${registro.specialty}</td>
          <td class="office">${registro.office}</td>
          <td class="turn">${registro.turn}</td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm return-button">Confirmar Retorno</button></td>
        </tr>
      `)
    })
  }
})});
```

Y tengo este metodo desde nodejs que me actualiza ese campo:

```
router.put('/records/update/:id', async(req,res)=>{
const records = await Records.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
{ status: true },
{ new: true }
);
res.json('recibido');});
```

Como hago para realizar dicha accion desde ajax?? se supone que en cada registro al dar click a ese boton se actualiza un campo de mi registro en mi base de datos de mongodb

Comment: En el parámetro `url` del ajax tienes que poner la que expones con Node, por ejemplo: `url: '/records/update/7'`.

Comment: Claro pero cual seria el esquema que debo de utilizar? porque el esquema que me genera las listas en pantalla es el que mostre al inicio de la pregunta, de ahi tambien me genera un boton, como hago para conectar ese boton con mi metodo put en node js??

Comment: Podrías añadir un onclick al botón con la id del registro y volver a hacer una llamada ajax a la ruta del node pasandole la id.